# Sort a dictionary with strings as values by number of forward slashes in the string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have a dictionary like this :

```
paths = {19: 'routes/web.php', 44: 'app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php', 27: 'app/Filters/Filters.php', 32: 'resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php', 21: 'composer.json', 39: '.env'}

prepared = [(key, value) for key, value in paths.items()]
```

I want to to sort them by order such that if the value of the dictionary contains 3 or more forward slashes they should be ordered by length of the longest in the first place, and then values(strings) which don't contain any forward slashes, and at last the values(strings) that contain 2 or 1 slashes which are to be ordered by length with the shortest first. The output should look like this :

```
  prepared >>>
  [(44, 'app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php'), (32, 'resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php'), (39, '.env'), (21, 'composer.json'), (19, 'routes/web.php'), (27, 'app/Filters/Filters.php')]
```

Any solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom key function which produces a `tuple`. You haven't specified what happens with ties so your desired output does not match, and there is no unique solution in the general case.

```
def sorter(x):
    n = x[1].count('/')
    i = -n if n >= 3 else 0
    j = 0 if n == 0 else 1
    k = n
    return i, j, k

prepared = sorted(paths.items(), key=sorter)

[(32, 'resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php'),
 (44, 'app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php'),
 (21, 'composer.json'),
 (39, '.env'),
 (19, 'routes/web.php'),
 (27, 'app/Filters/Filters.php')]
```